# How to Translate below MongoDB Shell code to Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have below mongodb shell code working :

```
  db.campaigns.aggregate([
                {$lookup: {from: "email_statistics", localField: "_id", foreignField: "campaign_id", as: "stats"}},
                { $unwind : "$stats" },
                { $match : { "stats.opened": true } },
                { $group : { _id : "$parent_user_id", total: { $sum: 1 } } },
                { $sort : { total: -1 } }
                ])
```

My application is using Morphia library to interact with mongoDB,i want to write above snippet in Morphia. I am having trouble in writing that

here is what i wrote but its giving me no results

```
Query<Campaign> q = DBHelper.getDB().createQuery(Campaign.class);
            q.disableValidation().filter("stats.replied", true);

Iterator<CountResult> aggregation = DBHelper.getDB().createAggregation(Campaign.class)
            .lookup("email_statistics", "id", "campaign_id", "stats")
            .unwind("stats")
            .match(q)
            .group("parent_user_id",grouping("count", accumulator("$sum", 1)))
            .sort(descending("count"))
            .limit(number_of_users)
            .aggregate(CountResult.class);

--------
```

Structue of Campaign and Statistic(email_statistics) is

```
Campaign 
{
id  
parent_user_id
}       

Statistic
{
campaign_id
replied
}
```

Comment: You need `"_id"` and not `"id"`. Here `.lookup("email_statistics", "_id", "campaign_id", "stats")`. These "should" be "string literals" referring to the actual field names, as opposed to class property names. A "debuging basic" of aggregation pipelines it to execute "one stage at a time". Then you clearly see where your mistakes are.

Comment: @NeilLunn i modified and got it working exactly as i intended. However the query is very time consuming,approx 3 minutes.. even on Mongo Shell, what optimization can i do in below shell query `db.campaigns.aggregate([
                {$lookup: {from: "email_statistics", localField: "_id", foreignField: "campaign_id", as: "stats"}},
                { $unwind : "$stats" },
                { $match : { "stats.opened": true } },
                { $group : { _id : "$parent_user_id",stats:{$push:"stats"}, total: { $sum: 1 } } },
                { $sort : { total: -1 } }
                ])`